# I am trying to do a simple connection with XAMPP and MySQL server, but whenever I try to enter data or connect to the database

Tags: php, mysql, database

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function verify_users() in C:\xampp\htdocs\codes\owy\login.php:73 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\codes\owy\login.php on line 73

code:

```php
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['user'])){
        $error = verify_users($_POST['user'],$_POST['password']);                                   
    }else{
        echo '<div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-md-offset-1" for="Email">Email</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter an email" name="user"id="user" type="text" value="" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-md-offset-1" for="Password">Password</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control text-box single-line password" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter a password" name="password" id="password" type="password" value=""/>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 form-inline">
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
            </div>
            </div>';
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code containing the connection to database so I can help you out further. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the error is straight forward, the function `verify_user`  does not exists. Did you forget to include a file which defines this function?

Comment: "Call to undefined function verify_users()" seems pretty self-explanatory. Did you have some reason to think that function should be defined? If so, what is that reason?

Answer (score -1):

You trying to call verify_users function but it's not defined before. Check your function definitions or please share your code lines before using that function.